# How to Add Product as different varieties like size as mentioned below in picture

Tags: magento1.9.3

I want to add product with three different sizes and whenever the size has been selected it should be active for user.

Anyone help me?[image: Example site for reference]

Comment: use configurable product type with super attribute **size**

Answer (score 1):

You can Use configurable product for that.

this is the tutorial for creating configurable product http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-configurable.html

and also as you show thumbnail of a simple product you can use Marius extension for simple product thumbnail https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher

Hope so above two links will help you

Answer (score 0):

Use Configurable Product or simple product with custom option for you need

A configurable product looks like a single product with drop-down lists of options for each variation. Each option is actually a separate simple product with a unique SKU, which makes it possible to track inventory for each product variation. You could achieve a similar effect by using a simple product with custom options, but without the ability to track inventory for each variation.

Check [This link](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/how-create-configurable-product.html#gref) for create configurable product.

And

Check [This link](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-create-product-custom-options.html#gref) for create simple product with custom option.